# How to determinate row and column of grid on hover in js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created a page to see the events in a sort of calendar. I wish I could add new events when I hover in empty sections by showing a "+". The code is as follows:

```js
$("#classroom_admin-orario-content").hover(function() {
  console.log("Mouse leave");
  $(this).find(".row").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".col").each(function() {
      $(this).hover(function() {
        var row = $(this).parent().index();
        var column = $(this).index();
        console.log("Row: " + row + " Col: " + column);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container-orario {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3em 3em auto;
}

.title {
  background: #217346;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.days {
  background: #f3f2f1;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: 3em 20px repeat(6, 1fr);
  top: 3em;
  z-index: 10;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dadce0;
}

.day {
  border-left: 1px solid #dadce0;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3em 20px repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 6em);
  row-gap: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.time {
  grid-column: 1;
  text-align: right;
  align-self: end;
  font-size: 80%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -1ex;
  color: #70757a;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.col {
  border-right: 1px solid #dadce0;
  grid-row: 1/span 24;
  grid-column: span 1;
}

.filler-col {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: 2;
  border-right: 1px solid #dadce0;
}

.row {
  grid-column: 2/-1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadce0;
}

.event {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.weekend {
  background-color: #f1f3f4;
}

.calendar1 {
  background-color: rgba(253, 197, 208, 0.7);
  color: #f8254e;
  border: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.calendar2 {
  background-color: rgba(254, 240, 219, 0.7);
  color: #fc9b10;
  border: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.calendar3 {
  background-color: rgba(247, 219, 254, 0.7);
  color: #e010fc;
  border: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.calendar4 {
  background-color: rgba(219, 227, 254, 0.7);
  color: #105bfc;
  border: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.calendar5 {
  background-color: rgba(183, 236, 253, 0.7);
  color: #2fc6d1;
  border: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-width: 2px;
}


/* .current-time {
  grid-row: 10;
  border-top: 2px solid #ea4335;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
}

.circle {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ea4335;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ea4335;
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
} */

.current {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.time-subtitle {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-orario h-full relative antialiased w-full">
  <div class="days" id="classroom_admin-orario-days">
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="day">Lun</div>
    <div class="day">Mar</div>
    <div class="day">Mer</div>
    <div class="day">Gio</div>
    <div class="day">Ven</div>
    <div class="day">Sab</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="classroom_admin-orario-content">

    <div class="time" style="grid-row:1">08:00</div>
    <div class="time" style="grid-row:2">09:00</div>
    <div class="time" style="grid-row:3">10:00</div>
    <div class="time" style="grid-row:4">11:00</div>
    <div class="time" style="grid-row:5">12:00</div>
    <div class="time" style="grid-row:6">13:00</div>
    <div class="time" style="grid-row:7">14:00</div>
    <div class="filler-col"></div>
    <div class="col" style="grid-column:3"></div>
    <div class="col" style="grid-column:4"></div>
    <div class="col" style="grid-column:5"></div>
    <div class="col" style="grid-column:6"></div>
    <div class="col" style="grid-column:7"></div>
    <div class="col" style="grid-column:8"></div>
    <div class="row" style="grid-row:1"></div>
    <div class="row" style="grid-row:2"></div>
    <div class="row" style="grid-row:3"></div>
    <div class="row" style="grid-row:4"></div>
    <div class="row" style="grid-row:5"></div>
    <div class="row" style="grid-row:6"></div>
    <div class="row" style="grid-row:7"></div>
    <!-- EVENT LIST -->
    <div class="event calendar1" style="grid-column: 3;grid-row: 2/span 2; ">Matematica<br><span class="time-subtitle">08:00 - 10:00</span></div>
    <div class="event calendar2" style="grid-column: 3;grid-row: 4/span 1;">Sistemi e Reti<br><span class="time-subtitle">10:00 - 11:00</span></div>
    <div class="event calendar3" style="grid-column: 3;grid-row: 5/span 1;">Educazione Fisica<br><span class="time-subtitle">11:00 - 12:00</span></div>
    <div class="event calendar4" style="grid-column: 3;grid-row: 6/span 1;">Inglese<br><span class="time-subtitle">12:00 - 13:00</span></div>
    <div class="event calendar5" style="grid-column: 3;grid-row: 7/span 1;">Italiano<br><span class="time-subtitle">13:00 - 14:00</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With JavaScript I can't even get printed in which row and column the cell under the cursor is. Thanks in advance

Result (with the events entered)
[image]

Comment: When the schedule is filled is it done by another function? The HTML isn't structured to accommodate content past the second column and first row. The jQuery in OP works for the standard rows and columns of a HTML table wherein the cells (`<td>`) are nested within the rows (`<tr>`). The HTML in OP has no such pattern, rows and columns only appear to intersect due to CSS, not HTML which is what the jQuery in the OP was designed for.

Comment: @zer00ne: The cells are filled by another code that processes the height of the event and adds it in the html under the last row (where there is the event list comment). I just added to the code some example having

Comment: It looks like the whole structure relies on CSS not on HTML -- so the standard way of using JS/jQ to manipulate the DOM will not work very well (more likely not at all). It only accounts for the content and position is totally dependent on CSS not where it is in the actual DOM. It doesn't actually add any HTML for the "cells" that are empty so there's nothing to reference with JS/jQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think this works. I've added an event listener to the container and added a data-row attribute to each row, and a data-column attribute to each column. At each mousemove it tests each row and column bounding rectangle to see if the mouse coordinates are within that element. If yes, it pulls the relevant data attribute in to the variables 'row' and 'col'.

HTML here:

```
<div class="content" id="classroom_admin-orario-content">
  <div class="time" style="grid-row:1">08:00</div>
  <div class="time" style="grid-row:2">09:00</div>
  <div class="time" style="grid-row:3">10:00</div>
  <div class="time" style="grid-row:4">11:00</div>
  <div class="time" style="grid-row:5">12:00</div>
  <div class="time" style="grid-row:6">13:00</div>
  <div class="time" style="grid-row:7">14:00</div>
  <div class="filler-col"></div>
  <div class="col" data-col="1" style="grid-column:3"></div>
  <div class="col" data-col="2" style="grid-column:4"></div>
  <div class="col" data-col="3" style="grid-column:5"></div>
  <div class="col" data-col="4" style="grid-column:6"></div>
  <div class="col" data-col="5" style="grid-column:7"></div>
  <div class="col" data-col="6" style="grid-column:8"></div>
  <div class="row" data-row="1" style="grid-row:1"></div>
  <div class="row" data-row="2" style="grid-row:2"></div>
  <div class="row" data-row="3" style="grid-row:3"></div>
  <div class="row" data-row="4" style="grid-row:4"></div>
  <div class="row" data-row="5" style="grid-row:5"></div>
  <div class="row" data-row="6" style="grid-row:6"></div>
  <div class="row" data-row="7" style="grid-row:7"></div>
  <!-- EVENT LIST -->
</div>
```

JS here:

```
var row;
var col;
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#classroom_admin-orario-content").mousemove(function(event) {
    row=-1;
    col=-1;
    const x=event.pageX-window.scrollX;
    const y=event.pageY-window.scrollY;   

    $('.row').each(function() {
      const rect=$(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
      if(x>=rect.left && x<rect.right && y>=rect.top && y<=rect.bottom) {
        row=$(this).attr('data-row');
      }
    });
    $('.col').each(function() {
      const rect=$(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
      if(x>=rect.left && x<rect.right && y>=rect.top && y<=rect.bottom) {
        col=$(this).attr('data-col');
      }
    });
    console.log("col="+col+" row="+row);
  });
});
```

It'll hopefully get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to use a custom attribute (e.g. the data- attribute) on each element to identify the row and column (or other unique identifier) so when you hover you can use jQuery's .attr method to get the details you need.

For custom attributes see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

jQuery .attr method is [here](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: This I could do for the events already created, but I need it for those to be created so that I hover in the empty cell and I get the "+"